# Multiple windows, but also multiple items on the task bar

Tags: wpf, taskbar

I'm setting up a program that has three different windows.  I'm just using ..

Window1 win1 = new Window1();
win1.show();

...for each of the extra windows.  The problem is that each window opens up a new tab on the taskbar.  Is there anyway that I can still have my three windows with only one related item on the taskbar?

If possible, I would not like to make them all child forms and have to sit inside of another box.

Thank you

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Set the ShowInTaskbar to false

```
<Window ShowInTaskbar="False" ... />
```

If you want to make the windows related together, like when you click one of them it brings them all, set the Owner before showing the window (assuming `this` is your main window)

```
Window1 w = new Window1();
w.Owner = this;
```

Answer (score 9):

Set the "secondary" windows' [ShowInTaskbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showintaskbar.aspx) property to false. Also it wouldn't hurt to set their [Owner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner.aspx) property to App.Current.MainWindow, so that the all the windows close (and hence the application exits) when the main window is closed.

Comment: Sorry for now voting you as the answer, but they were both the same so I went for the first one.

Comment: That's cool. I left my post here because it has links to the MSDN references for the properties.